# Keeping an GA Kernel after the OS hits its EOL (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: kernel

I have a laptop (Toshiba Satellite A200, circa 2008) with Ubuntu 16.04 on it and that works only with the GA kernel 4.4
I had to manually degrade the HWE kernel (4.15) to make it work due to shutdown hangs.
I checked AskUbuntu & the other forums, and it could be a problem related to ACPI, but my limited understanding of kernels let me to simply degrade the kernel, so now it shuts down without issue.

Problem is : Since Ubuntu 16.04 will reach its EOL in April 2021, can I keep this kernel (4.4) with the new Ubuntu version (likely 20.04 or 18.04) ? Or do I have to compile it myself (something I'm definitely not able to do right now) ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Whilst Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will release end of standard support (and EOL for the LTS), it's life will continue via Ubuntu 16.04 ESM (supported by Canonical, but ESM releases are off-topic here).  See https://ubuntu.com/esm   Back-porting security patches yourself to the 4.4 kernel for use on later releases is a rather technical job, as difficult if not more than getting the HWE kernel running on your current box, so ESM is your easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will reach end of standard support April 2021 (and thus EOL for the LTS), it's life will continue via Ubuntu 16.04 ESM (supported by Canonical, but please note ESM releases are off-topic here).

See https://ubuntu.com/esm

Back-porting security patches yourself to the 4.4 kernel for use on later releases is a rather technical job, as difficult if not more than getting the HWE kernel running on your current box, so ESM is your easiest solution.

*Yes, patching will involve re-compiling the kernel after it's patched*

Comment: Ok. That's why I was afraid... Thanks for the clarification. I will probably just try to resolve the shutdown hangs (I already tried passing kernel options : acpi=off...etc to no avail).